# virtual function in template inherited class

Tags: c++, templates

I am new to templates and I have searched the web for this error but I don't know how to fix it it.
Already checked [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

State.h

```
template <class entityType>
class State
{
public:
    State() = default;
    virtual void Enter(entityType * owner);

};
```

EnterMine.h

```
#include "State.h"

class Miner;
class EnterMine : public State<Miner>
{
public:
    EnterMine() = default;
    virtual void Enter(Miner *) {

    };
};
```

and Miner.cpp is blank

and the problem appears in main.cpp

```
#include "EnterMine.h"

int main()
{
    EnterMine a;
}
```

The error I get is a linking error :

> LNK2001   unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall State::Enter(class Miner *)" (?Enter@?$State@VMiner@@@@UAEXPAVMiner@@@Z)

Comment: Where is `EnterMine::EnterMine()` defined?

Comment: it is not defined. Should I define it?.I tried defining it explicitly but the error didn't dissapear. I also tried inheriting from State like so : EnterMine::EnterMine() : State<Miner>() {

}

Comment: Please don't modify the code in your question, because then comments and answers no longer make sense. You can add code, but make it clear that code was added later and was not part of the original question.

Comment: "_The error I get is a linking error_" OK, and what is your linker config and resulting command then?

Comment: @pbn That's not how static initialisation works. The initialising expression will only be evaluated and assigned to the static object during the first call to the function.

Comment: @underscore_d Indeed. Must have overlooked the static modifier there.

Comment: And where is `State::Enter` now defined?

Comment: Why should i define it anyway?

Comment: @pbn sorry for modifying the question so many times.

Comment: Because it is used somewhere in your code. Maybe you meant a pure virtual function? Then write `virtual void Enter(entityType * owner) = 0;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Note: this answer was written for the original question, it has been completely rewritten after that.)

Every function that is declared and used, should be defined somewhere.

It seems that you declare `EnterMine::EnterMine()` but never define it. If this constructor does nothing, either omit it (it will be [implicitly defined by a compiler](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor#Implicitly-defined_default_constructor)), or mark it as `= default;`.

```
class EnterMine : public State<Miner>
{
public:
    EnterMine() = default;
    ...
};
```

This also applies to the `State::State()` constructor.

Comment: could be related to Miner class?

Comment: @nickk2002, add the new error to your question. If you implemented constructors correctly and `.cpp` files are included into your project, you should not get the same unresolved external error.

Answer (score 0):

Even though it's a singleton, you're still calling the constructor. Thus, you will still need to define the constructor.

In fact, you need to define every function you declare in your header.